# I need an explanation on why the variance of the distribution of noise term is considered as such

Tags: statistics, time-series

AR: $\epsilon_t=\rho\epsilon_{t-1}+\eta_t$ with $\eta_t $ i.i.d. $N(0, \sigma^2), t=1,...,n$ and $\epsilon_0=0$ with $\eta_0\sim N(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\rho^2}),\lvert\rho\rvert<1;$

Why is the variance of $\eta_0 = \frac{\sigma^2}{1-\rho^2}$?
Is it correct to assume Var$(\epsilon_{t-1})=\sigma^2$?

Comment: no it does not,it is focused on \epsilon where as i need to know why the variance of \eta at time 0 is chosen so.

Comment: Indeed $\eta_0$ is not even part of the process, so some context is missing